# How to tell asdf to select the second version of nodejs from inside .tools-versions

Tags: asdf, asdf-vm

I am trying to temporary switch node version to the second version lists in `.tool-versions` file but I was not able to find any options for this.

```bash
$ cat .tool-versions
nodejs 18.19.1 20.11.1
```

This is problematic because I have a CI pipeline that is uspposed to run using the alternative version, and the exact version is mentioned only in `.tool-versions.`

Running `asdf list nodejs` returns all available versions, so it might include other version not listed in `.tool-versions` and I do not want to accidentally use these.